# How to display the latest Record

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display only the latest record from usersId.

How do I create a query that would give me the latest ordersId from usersId?

The table looks like this:
[image: The table looks like this]

this the query that I use but it displays all the ordersId:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE usersId=?
```

Comment: How do you define the "latest" row? Please share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output. It would be even better if you added your attempts to resolve the question

Comment: @NicoHaase *"the latest ordersId"*

Comment: @Dharman does this only refer to the largest ordersId value per usersId, or could this also be linked to the orderDate column in any way? Is it safe to assume that the IDs are assigned in strictly ascending order?

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest one record, please

1. set order by OrdersID in descending order, and then
2. get only 1 record by using "limit 0, 1"

So please change the

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE usersId=?
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE usersId=? order by ordersId desc limit 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LIMIT` clause as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE usersId=? 
 order by orderdate desc limit 1;
```

OR you can use analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
select * from
(SELECT t.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by usersId order by orderdate desc) as rn 
  FROM `orders` t WHERE usersId=?) t
where rn = 1
```

`row_number` solution is useful when you want the latest data for multiple `usersid`.

Comment: So what's the difference between the two?

Comment: If you want the multiple user's latest data `usersId in (?,?,?)` then analytical function can give latest data for multiple `usersid`

Answer (score 0):

You are binding $uid before setting it to the user_id from session you should assign first & then bind.

```
$uid=$_SESSION['userid'];
$stmt->bind_param("s",$uid);
```

Comment: Why would that make any difference? It's binding by reference.